# Big O of ceil(log_p(n))

Tags: asymptotics, approximation

I have the function $$f(n) = \lceil \log_p(n) \rceil$$ where $n>0$ and $p 
\ge 2$. What is the Big O approximation for $n \rightarrow \infty$?

How can I derive it based on the known definition of Big 0?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the definition of ceiling function,

$$\log_p n \le f(n) < 1 + \log_p n$$

For the case $p > 1$, for large $n > p$, the upper bound is

$$1+\log_p n = \log_p pn < \log_p n^2 = 2\log_p n = \frac{2}{\log p}\log n$$

---

For the case $0 < p < 1$, for large enough $n>\dfrac1p$, $f(n)$ and $(1+\log_p n)$ are negative. So considering the absolute values,

$$|1 + \log_p n| < |f(n)| \le |\log_p n|$$

The upper bound is

$$|\log_p n| = -\log_p n = \frac1{-\log p}\cdot\log n$$

Additionally, for the interest of big-$\Theta$ notation, the lower bound is

$$|1 + \log_p n| = -1-\log_p n = -\log_p pn = \frac{\log pn}{-\log p}$$

For large $n > \frac1{p^2}$, i.e. $p > \frac 1{\sqrt n}$,

$$\frac{\log pn}{-\log p} > \frac{\log \sqrt n}{-\log p} = \frac1{-2\log p} \cdot \log n$$

($-\log p$ is a positive constant)

Comment: Thanks! Can we then say $f(n) \text{ is } O(1+\log_pn)$? I mean $2\log_pn$ is much larger then $f(n)$, so $1+\log_p(n)$ is a better upper bound.

Comment: Yes, so you can even say $f(n)$ is $O(\log n)$. But the case where $0<p<1$ is yet to be proven.

Comment: Oh nice, I won't have a $p$ between $0$ and $1$ in my work, so then I can say $O(\log_p(n))$.

Comment: @N.Younger Then you should mention that $p>1$ in your question.

Comment: That is true! I've changed it, and thank you for your fast and helpful answer.

Comment: When I plot the exact $f(n)$ and $\log_p(n)$, then $\log_p(n)$ is a lower bound. I need an upper bound, then I have to say $O(1+\log_p(n))$, or?

Comment: You should double check the definition of big-$O$ notation. Since $$f(n) \le 2\log_p n = \frac{2}{\log p}\cdot \log n$$ for large enough $n$ (i.e. $n > p$), $f$ is bounded above (up to a constant factor) by $\log n$ asymptotically, so $f(n) = O(\log n)$.

Comment: @N.Younger $$O(\log_p n) = O(2\log_p n) = O(1+\log_p n).$$